# C# get current system time

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime

So I have a program that I need to be able to get the current time. This is a winform and I have a timer that starts up when the winform is loaded and the interval is 1000. Every tick it checks the time and sets a label on the winform to display that time. I use `DateTime.Now.Hour;` to determine the hour (which is just what I need). My problem is even though this code is on a timer it only displays the time that was when the winform started and doesnt update it. What do I do to get the current and updating hour of the day?

EDIT:

Here is the code

```
//code for hour variable
private int time = DateTime.Now.Hour;

//Code for timer
private void mainTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //code run every time mainTimer gets a tick
            label1.Text = time.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: label1.Text = DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString();

Comment: the problem with your code is that you set field once and the value will not be changed. instead you can use the code in my previous code or create the property:

Comment: private int Time { get { return DateTime.Now.Hour; }}

Comment: Thanks alexander that did the trick. Figured out why the variable didnt work too :)

Answer (score 9):

Your class field *won't be re-evaluated* again until you set it explicitly.

This is how you should do it:

```
label1.Text = DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    private void Clock(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime dtn = DateTime.Now.Hour;
        label1.Text = dtn.ToString();
    }
```

then put timer tick on it